# Migration of WooCommerce site

Tags: migration

I am new in WordPress. I am trying to migrate a WooCommerce site. What are the steps to Migrate a WooCommerce site? Where is the location of `.htaccess` file in a WooCommerce site?

I migrated files and databases. I changed setting in `wp-config.php` file. I changed site URL in `wp-options` table of the database. But I found that my migrated site is not looking like the previous site, even I am getting `Not Found` error while I am trying to browse categories pages.

Could anyone say where is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to edit `wp-config.php` file and `wp-options` table. You have to change **all** URLs and file paths in your database, including those serialized.

Use [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) or [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugins to do so.

`.htaccess` file resides in the same server directory as `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Thanks @Max Yudin for your nice reply. WP Migrate DB is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Woocommerce sites are basically WordPress sites, so follow [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for details you may have missed.

2) If you changed domains - and it sounds like you did since you changed the site url in `wp-options` table - you should use [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) in order to correctly change the old URLs in the database to the new domain.

3) 404's can be cause by wrong permalinks; it's always a good idea to always re-save your permalinks after a move.

4) To diagnose other errors, try Debug. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG . Add

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`

to wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

5) To check for other 404s, network errors and Javascript console errors, the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What if the migration of the WooCommerce website has stopped debug.log working, like in my case?